# Allow non-admins to access the Customize theme page

Tags: customization, wp-admin

I'm using a theme that has a very robust customizer and I want users other than an admin to be able to use the customizer so they can customize what their site looks like. The URL for the customizer is at:
`http://localhost/mulitsite1/wp-admin/customize.php`

Is there a way that I can give access to this page for someone that has an editor type role without modifying the core Wordpress `wp-admin/customize.php` file?

EDIT: I looked into the `wp-admin/customize.php` file and saw the following line of code:

```
} elseif ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
```

If I give the user the capability like this:

```
get_role('subscriber')->add_cap('edit_theme_options');
```

They have access to the customizer that I want however, I don't want them to be able to switch themes, change widgets, menus or the sidebars so can I only give them access to the customize option?

Since the following line exists on line 15 of the `wp-admin/customize.php` file:

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'customize' ) ) {
```

I tried to add that as the only capability:

```
get_role('subscriber')->add_cap('customize');
```

This didn't give me the access that I needed though.

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to do it that way. It could be that you are facing a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @kaiser Ok, basically I'm trying to allow my users to customize their site from outside the wordpress dashboard so they think they aren't using Wordpress. If for some reason a user knows the URL to see the profile.php page within the Admin section I'm trying to limit what they can do. If I only give them the customize capability then I don't have to worry about if they get to the dashboard somehow and what they can do there.

Comment: In other words: You are trying to redirect everybody to the public page (who is not an admin)?

Comment: @kaiser Yes but they need to have that capability. I actually asked another question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178214/change-the-return-url-from-the-customizer to try and ensure that when they cancelled they would go back to the public page and not back into the Dashboard again.

Comment: Why do they need to have access to the Customizer?

Comment: @kaiser Every school will have their own multisite that I want to allow them to style, create layouts like they want just to allow them to make it feel like their own and not a standard site that everyone else has. The customizer already has all this functionality built in so I would love to give them access so they can design their site as they want.

Comment: @kaiser Also if I end up going with the approach of giving them access to the dashboard then I only want them to have access to the Customize link and nothing else.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put all the information from the comments into it. I'll clean the comments up (or you can do it yourself) if you ping me afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution and it's worked:

```
get_role('editor')->add_cap('edit_theme_options');
```

It's possible since Version 3.0 in Wordpress

Comment: OP noted in the question that he already tried it, but as he wrote: `I don't want them to be able to switch themes, change widgets, menus or the sidebars`.